# How do I detect if a table exists (which doesn't have a class or ID)

Tags: jquery

I’m having a problem trying to detect if a table exists using jQuery.  The table has no class or ID.

What I’m trying to achieve is to not have the following code fire unless a table exists:

```
function tableAltRows()
    {
        $("#content table tr:even").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("alt");
        });
    }
$(tableAltRows);
```

So I changed the last line to:

```
if ($('table').length > 0) {
    $(tableAltRows);
}
```

But the line checking the table length never returns anything other than 0.  As a test, if I change it to == 0 it calls the tableAltRows function.  I’m not that familiar with jQuery, so I assume I’m missing something obvious?

Comment: How is this table created? Do you have an example page?

Comment: Where/when/how do you call this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that you're not calling your function when the DOM is ready. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('table').length) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the element before it exists, it will not work.

You can:

1. Insert the script after the element
2. Make the script execute when the page is ready

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UbJNT/)